# Solid angle with Stokes theorem

Tags: vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates, vector-fields, stokes-theorem, solid-angle

Trying to evaluate a solid angle of a spherical cap with Stokes theorem:

$$
\begin{gathered}
\int_\Omega \frac{\hat r}{r^2}\cdot d\vec\omega\\
A = - \frac{\cot\theta}{r} \hat\phi\\
\nabla \times A = \frac{\hat r}{r^2}
\end{gathered}
$$

Since in this case $A$ is not continuous at $\theta=0$, I've considered a second reversed inner loop taken to the limit of 0, and then obtained:
$$
\int_\Omega\frac{\hat r}{r^2}\cdot d\vec\omega =
\int_\gamma -\frac{\cot\theta}{r} \cdot r\sin\theta\space d\phi -
\int_{\gamma_0} A\cdot d\vec\gamma = -2\pi\cos\theta + 2\pi
$$
This is the normal solid angle formula for the cap of a sphere.

Then I tried with a different $A$:
$$
\begin{gathered}
A = -\phi\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\space\hat\theta\\
\nabla\times A = \frac{\hat r}{r^2}
\end{gathered}
$$

But the tangent vector of the loop $\gamma$ has only $\hat\phi$ component, which means:
$$
A\cdot d\vec\gamma = 0
$$
So the whole integral evaluates to $0$.

Am I missing something simple here?

EDIT:

Resolved by achille hui in the comments. $A$ is not continuous in the second case too because it jumps a value when $\phi$ turns from $2\pi$ to $0$. The cap is a multivalued point for $A$ as well.
Both issues are solved simultaneously by making a small loop near the cap, then breaking both loops at $\phi'$ near 0 and then stitching them together instead along $\hat\theta$. So the integral is now non-zero and evaluates to the correct formula (in the limit of $\phi'\rightarrow0$, the angle at which the loops were broken).

Comment: Your second $A$ is not single valued on the cap $\theta \le \theta_0$. In particular, it has a jump type discontinuity at the cut $\phi = 0$ / $\phi = 2\pi$.

Comment: Indeed, I missed that cut! Now that I've split the loop even more (in order to not have the cut), it works quite nicely! Thanks a lot! Can comments be upvoted?